# How to solve this system of nonlinear differential equation?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following system of equation:
$$ 
x_1' = (2-t)x_1+(t-1)x_2 \\
x_2' =  2(1-t)x_1+(2t-1)x_2.\\
$$

We, therefore, have a system of the following form $$\dot{X}=A(t)X(t).$$ I am not sure how to go about solving this system since $A$ is not a matrix of constants. Any hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: $(1,1) $ is an eigenvector with $1$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: Did you find the eigenvalue of $A(t)$?

Comment: the eigenvalues of $A (t ) $ are $1$ and $t $.

Comment: And $(1,2)$ is the eigenvector with $t$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: The system is linear. I think you mean non-constant.

Comment: Subtract the second equation from the first.  Can you proceed now?